# Creating an NSCalendar to be PST timezone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsdate, nscalendar

What is the way to create an NSCalendar to have its timezone be PST?

Well this still be the case if the iPhone is in LA (PST) or NYC (EST)? Will the code adjust based on the location/timezone of the device?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you get a calendar using `currentCalendar`, then it will be for the current timezone of the user, so if you explicitly specify the timezone of the calendar then it will have that timezone, so, for example:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Pacific"];
[cal setTimeZone:zone];
```

If you want a calendar with the user's current timezone, then you omit the setting of the timezone.

If you want a calendar that responds to the user's change in settings, then you get an `autoUpdatingCurrentCalendar`:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar autoUpdatingCurrentCalendar];
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'if the iphone is in a different timezone'. You asked how to get a calendar in a specific timezone; once you set the timezone it stays with that calendar instance. If you want the calendar to report on the user's timezone, you use either the `currentCalendar` or `autoUpdatingCurrentCalendar` and do not specify the timezone.

Comment: So if a person is in Los Angeles at 2:05pm and another in NYC at 5:05pm and I set the calendar to be PST, then when I write to my server both times will be 2:05pm correct?

Comment: The question is *what* are you writing to the server. A point in time (an `NSDate`) is the same point in time regardless of what timezone you ultimately decide to represent it in. If you turn it into a *string* (e.g. using an `NSDateFormatter`, then at that point the timezone comes into effect).

Comment: I am turning it into a string (code) to keep track of groups of things in 4 hour increments

Comment: so how do i get the strings to be in the same timezone on the server if someone is in LA and someelese is in NYC?